# Deserialize this json in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json-deserialization

I have this json response:

```
  {

    "tracked_until": "1483704963",
    "solo_competitive_rank": "4066",
    "competitive_rank": "3821",
    "mmr_estimate": {
        "estimate": 3971,
        "stdDev": 215.26495302301302,
        "n": 20
    },
    "profile": {
        "account_id": 131505839,
        "personaname": "LeG",
        "name": null,
        "cheese": 1,
        "steamid": "76561198091771567",
        "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c0/c09ca9b316ff7bf7dccba6f5a32aba97b8dba05c.jpg",
        "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c0/c09ca9b316ff7bf7dccba6f5a32aba97b8dba05c_medium.jpg",
        "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c0/c09ca9b316ff7bf7dccba6f5a32aba97b8dba05c_full.jpg",
        "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/LegLabs/",
        "last_login": "2016-11-11T13:13:18.651Z",
        "loccountrycode": "AL"
    }
}
```

Using an Online Tool, I created these classes:

```
<Serializable>
    Public Class mmr_estimate
        Public Property estimate As String
        Public Property stdDev As String
        Public Property n As String
    End Class

    <Serializable>
    Public Class profile
        Public Property account_id As String
        Public Property personaname As String
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property cheese As String
        Public Property steamid As String
        Public Property avatar As String
        Public Property avatarmedium As String
        Public Property avatarfull As String
        Public Property profileurl As String
        Public Property last_login As String
        Public Property loccountrycode As String
    End Class

    <Serializable>
    Public Class RootObject
        Public Property tracked_until As String
        Public Property solo_competitive_rank As String
        Public Property competitive_rank As String
        Public Property mmr_estimate As mmr_estimate
        Public Property profile As profile
    End Class
```

Then I use this code to deserialize it:

```
Dim steamData As String = ' the json contents above
Dim myjss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim playerDictionary = myjss.Deserialize(Of List(Of RootObject))(steamData)
```

But the result I get is nothing, playerDictionary has 0 items, when it should have 1 item with the contents of the json parsed into KeyValuePairs.

If I use this piece of code

```
Dim data = myjss.DeserializeObject(steamData)
```

and then run a for each loop on the data elements, I can see the contents of data when debugging, but I don't know how to work with them like that, since they are just objects which I'm having trouble converting into KeyValuePairs, who in themselves may contain arrays of KeyValuePairs.

What I'm trying to get is the values of solo_competitive_rank, competitive_rank and steamid, but if I can't get the whole contents deserialized, I can't do that.

Are the declared classes wrong?

Comment: *That* json has just one item - no `[...]` there -  so dont deserialize to a List(of) or array.  The classes are supoptimal but will work.  Look at the data - for `steadmid`  the data is quoted so it is a string. `cheese` and others is not, so it should be integer.  If you do a lot of this, you might want to use JSON.NET

Comment: ok, removing the List (of), gives me another error which is exception {"Cannot convert null to a value type."} System.InvalidOperationException

Also, I edited the property types to their proper ones, (some ints, doubles and a datetime).

Comment: With *that* exact data?  The only null is name which can be converted to string.

Comment: Yes, apparently the problem was the Date, i had switched it to DateTime and it threw the error, changed it back to string, and it's okay now.

Answer (score 0):

but with this solution you use not the class RootObject.
With first method, your JSON want in the list with key and value.
This is only for JSON Array. :(

rg